# How to recognition gender based on the whole body using Deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, dataset, data-science

I can identify gender using the face image.
Is there any way to identify gender based on a whole human body? If yes, do anybody has pre dataset to train a model

Answer (score 1):

[SMPL eXpressive](https://smpl-x.is.tue.mpg.de/) has a gender classifier based on the input image of the human body (and 2D keypoint detections).

> We train a gender detector and use this to automatically determine what body
>   model to use, either male, female or gender neutral.

Comment: Do you have python code to test my own images using SMPL eXpressive? if yes, please share with me let me test it.